# How to install latest Telegram Desktop on a 32 bit computer running Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, 32-bit, telegram

There is a big problem about telegram client on a 32-bit arch systems.

All 32-bit (i386) versions of the telegram messenger are outdated now (2022-10-22)

All right, but this is a problem for a many people who can't get a 64bit systems at all or it is too difficult in the some places on  our Earth.

May be someone can help with this problem? Is there any way to use telegram client on 32-bit system?

I want to use it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: This problem is actual for any 32-bit version of ubuntu. For example: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: 18.04 only has a few months before EOL and it sounds like you are not using any version of Ubuntu. You might try your question on this other site. https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is true situation. And many old computers are worked today.

Comment: Alternatively, switch to ArchLinux32. It is hard to install and set up, but you will get all the updated packages compiled for 32bit. https://archlinux32.org/packages/?q=telegram-desktop You can also use Debian Sid LXDE 32 bit. It too is a "semi-rolling release" with latest packages.

Answer (score 4):

You have several options.

---

### PPA

The telegram desktop [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/telegram) by the atareao-team hosts 32-bit (i386) version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt update
sudo apt install telegram
```

---

### Telegram Web

You can use https://web.telegram.org as a desktop app with Firefox or Chromium (by creating desktop shortcuts).

---

### Switching Distro

Debian Sid and Arch Linux 32 are rolling release distros (with latest packages) that support the 32-bit architecture.
You can also use the Raspberry Pi OS (which is very lightweight and suitable for old computers) based on Debian Bullseye, and switch to the Debian Sid repositories.